# On Android, why can View.OnClickListener instances call their parent's methods as though they were their own?

Tags: java, android, namespaces, onclick, listeners

I have a main Activity class that has a button to which I assign an OnClickListener:

```
public class MyMainClass extends Activity {
    protected void initWidgets() {
        btAddProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAddProfile);
        btAddProfile.setOnClickListener(onAddProfileClick);
    }

    protected View.OnClickListener onAddProfileClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addHotspot();
        }
    };

    protected void addHotspot(){
        //doStuff
    }
}
```

The onAddProfileClick instance is a child of MyMainClass, and yet it's able to call MyMainClass's addHotspot() function without referencing MyMainClass.  How is that possible?

Comment: FYI this is not an android-specific phenomenom.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not their parent, but their enclosing class, and they may do that as they are associated with the enclosing object and in its scope. (there is an implicit call to `MyMainClass.this.addHotspot()` when you write `addHotspot()`)

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. (I don't have enough reputation to vote you up yet, sorry!)